# How can I mount an FTP to a drive letter in windows?

Tags: windows, ftp, mount

I'd like to mount an FTP to a drive letter in windows, I've used Novell's NetDrive, but there are two main problems, 1) it tends to slow down computer **alot** 2) it doesn't seem to work at all under Vista.

Are there any applications that will allow me to mount a remote FTP to a local Drive letter, or is there a method built into Vista for it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have used [WebDrive](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/index.html) for several years without any trouble.

Comment: This is a good one, I've used it in the past, the only real downside to it is that it's not free, but good otherwise.

Comment: Correct that it is not free, but it is worth the money.

Comment: I agree. webDrive is awesome.

Comment: Going on three years later, and WebDrive is still my #1 choice for integrated Windows shell FTP.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/). Amazing. They have a version for Windows and Mac.

Comment: The windows version was formerly known as SFTPDrive.

If you're going to recommend it over other programs, please give some indication why.

Answer (score 4):

WebDrive is probably the best method for getting an FTP server mapped to a Drive Letter.

However, if you really just want easy access, and don't mind having the FTP connection mapped to a pseudo-folder under "My Network Drives" in XP or under "Computer" in Vista, then you can follow the instructions from this [website](http://cybernetnews.com/2007/09/27/cybernotes-map-a-ftp-to-a-drive-in-windows/).

Quick [tutorial](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/ftp/how-can-i-map-to-an-ftp-server-as-a-drive-) for mapping ftp drive from command line.

Comment: the link to website was exactly what I was looking for, without any third parties.. and there's another link at the end of the article that shows how to map a drive letter as well.. it's brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [FTPDrive](http://www.killprog.com/fdrve.html), a free Windows utility for mounting an FTP Server as a local hard-disk drive and view directories in a Windows folder structure.

The utility creates a virtual FTP disk in Windows Explorer with a drive letter of your choice from where you can open, view, access, download and save files as if they were on a local drive.

Here are some features from last version (3.5):

- both unsecure and secure connections (SSL/TLS)
- FTP drive completely implements read operations for FTP files
- compatible with many applications, except those, that uses own drivers to access files (partial write operations implementation)
- intercept & open ftp:// links from any other application
- cache directories structure and read files data

Comment: Appreciated, will look into.

Comment: Way too old. Didn't work for me.  Doesn't seem to have had a code revision since 2006?

Answer (score 1):

For example FTP Drive or Web Drive. Of course FTP in general is not very recommended any more because it's so unsecure.

SF doesn't allow to add links so just google for "FTP Drive".

Comment: New users can't set links. You have to get reputation. +1 :-)

Comment: You can't uninstall "FTP Drive" from Windows XP without rebooting your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this isn't quite what you're looking for, but you might find it useful. I used use it for connecting to unix boxes that didn't have Samba installed. If you just type in the Windows Explorer Address bar something like this:
ftp://username@ftpserver/../../path/

It's not quite a mapped drive, but you do have full Windows Explorer copy and paste, which is handy.

You might have to play around with the path part, that's why I put in the /../../ bit.

Comment: The full syntax for this is prot://username:password@server/path/to/folder/
for ftp it is commonly ftp://username:password@domain.tld

Answer (score 1):

All mentioned programs like WebDrive, FtpDrive etc have one single problem. They are usually not visible in backup programs as they do not appear as normal `Fixed` or `Removable` drive. So programs like Symantec Exec Backup 2010, Symantec Exec Backup 2010 System Recovery simply don't see it (even thou it is shown in Windows Explorer).

I've tested those programs and this was the main problem (those programs didn't see it the same way as Windows Explorer does) as i needed the ftp mount letter to have backup moved directly to ftp drive.

However I did find nice program that backup programs seems to `see` it. I've not yet tested how backup will work directly to that drive but I do have good feeling about this (at least programs see it). Without further ado [FtpUse](http://www.ferrobackup.com/ftpuse/) is your man! :-)

Comment: @MadBoy... yea FtpUse was the best option here I thought

Answer (score 0):

I had this question today as well, and came across this good article, telling about 2 programs mentioned, SftpDrive and Webdrive:

http://systembash.com/content/map-drive-letter-sftp-ssh-review/

Answer (score -1):

Why reinvent the wheel by using a 3rd party application?

On Vista (or Windows 7):

```
1.Click on the Start menu and choose Computer
2.Click on Map network drive towards the top of the Computer 
3.Click Connect to a Web site that you can use to store your 
  documents and pictures.
4.This will take you to the Add Network Location Wizard. Click 
   the Next button.
5.Pick Choose a custom network location and click Next
6.Enter the path to your server (note the examples of how the 
  paths should be entered) and click Next.
7.Uncheck Log on Anonymously and enter your user name for the 
  site, then click Next.
8.Type in the name you’d like to give this site (this is the name 
  that you will see in your Computer window) and click Next.
9.The wizard’s work is done. Click Finish and a window will open 
  showing the site. You will be prompted for a password unless you’ve 
  previously used Explorer to ftp to the site and the password was cached.
10.You can now work with your files just like you would in the 
   Explorer.
11.You’ll see a link to the site in your Computer window. Now you’ve 
   got easy access to your files on the remote server!
```

Comment: I'd say this is the best method on here, as seen in the link in [Steve's answer](http://serverfault.com/a/6143/51711)

Comment: The original question was how to assign a drive letter to a network share. Your solution will not do it.

Comment: @karategod - I disagree.  The original question is about mounting a FTP site as a windows drive letter.  Please remove your downvote.